# What to do if half the answer given to question is wrong?

Tags: support, specific-question, answers

A really high reputation user [wrote an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3187770/proof-explanation-of-every-nonnegative-function-can-be-written-as-the-increasing) to one of my questions.

I had spent a lot of time thinking on his answer and I arrived to the conclusion that it's wrong unless the theorem is false.

The problem is in the part of  increasing  of the sequence

What should be done here?

Comment: Leave a comment, downvote, vote to delete.  There really isn't much else that you can do.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I leave a comment but he did not reply.

Comment: If I vote to delete, would be just half his answer ( the other half is correct) ?

Comment: With your current reputation, you can't vote to delete other posts. However, if the OP didn't reply, then just downvote and move on... you can't force someone to do something.

Comment: @user178403 Even mistakes are valuable, in their own way, as long as their score reflects their correctness. I don't think it is good practice to vote to delete an answer simply because it contains a mistake (which would seem to be the case in a half-wrong answer). Voting and a comment will do the job.  In a lot of cases, the author will self-delete if the error is bad enough. The ideal candidates for deletion among solutions are those that are devoid of anything useful at all.

Comment: If your thinking about the problem led to a solution, posting a fully correct Answer in the situation described would be helpful.   Since the Question at issue was asked by you, it might be better to be patient, esp. if you are in doubt.

Comment: @hardmath in doubt? no, I am sure is wrong.